# How to Integrate Dynamic Jasper 4.0 wiht Struts2

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am Facing problem while integrating dynamic jasper 4.0 with struts2.

i saw the example they gave on the dynamic jasper website

it stated that

```
<result-type name="dynamic-jasper" class="ar.com.fdvs.dj.struts2.DJStruts2Result"/>
```

but the above class is not there in the DynamicJasper4.jar

any solution or help is highly appreciated thanks in advance

thanks for the help buddy.

after adding the jar i tried integrating it with struts2 but got error

There is no result type defined for type 'dynamic-jasper'

```
<package name="report" extends="struts-default,jasperreports-default">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"></result-type>
            <result-type name="dynamic-jasper" class="ar.com.fdvs.dj.struts2.DJStruts2Result"/>
        </result-types>

<action name="ShowReport" class="hris.report.action.GetReportAction">
              <result name="success" type="dynamic-jasper">
                <param name="dynamicReport">dr</param>
                <param name="layoutManager">classic</param>
                <param name="format">PDF</param>
            </result>
        </action>
   </package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an extra dependency for struts 2 compatibiliti.  it is no bundled in main jar.

http://archiva.fdvs.com.ar/repository/public1/ar/com/fdvs/DynamicJasper-Struts2/1.3/

Comment: hey buddy i treid integrating in struts2 this